# how can i know the length of the string in each array

Tags: java

I have a question please 
how can I know the length of  the string in each array?
for example

```
String m []={"hi","world"};
```

I want to know what is the length of m[1] ?

thank all

Comment: Java String object has a length method so just use m[1].length() - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: int length = m[0].length();

Comment: I see only one array. Do you mean length of *each string in array*?

Answer (score 3):

For example:

```
int length = m[0].length();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the method from String-Object: length

```
String m []={"hi","world"};
m[1].length();
```